# Output error in multiplication of two linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to multiply two linked list and i have used basic maths multiplication concept. Picked up a list item multiplied it the other linked list items and stored the result into another linked list. I have successfully achieved in doing so and correct multiplication also gets stored in the resultant linked list. But I am facing problem in adding the result linked list. The sum at every step is correctly calculated but at the last step garbage value replaces the sum. Please help me if my logic is wrong.

```
int multiply(struct node *first, struct node *second)
{
    struct node *ans = NULL;
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *rev_first = NULL;
    struct node *rev_second = NULL;
    int i, temp, mul, ten, carry=0, sum = 0;
    rev_first = reverse(first);
    rev_second = reverse(second);
    while(rev_first != NULL)
    {
        ten = 1;
        sum = 0;
        head = rev_second;
        while(head != NULL)
        {
            mul = (rev_first->data) * (head->data);
            carry = mul / 10;
            temp = mul % 10;
            sum = sum + (temp * ten);
            ten = ten * 10;
            head = head->next;
        }
        push(&ans, sum);
        rev_first = rev_first->next;
    }
    sum = 0;
    head = reverse(ans);
    for(mul = 1;head != NULL;(mul *= 10))
    {
        sum = sum + (mul * (head->data));
        head = head->next;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Are you running into integer overflow? How long are the linked lists?

Comment: just added 3 digits into the linked lists. i had changed sum to long from int but still same problem occours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the following logic errors in your code:

1. You forgot to initialize `carry` to `0` before the start of the inner `while` loop.
2. You forgot to use the `carry` when computing the terms using multiplication.
3. You forgot to use the `carry` after the end of the inner `while` loop.

Here's the corrected function.

```
int multiply(struct node *first, struct node *second)
{
    struct node *ans = NULL;
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *rev_first = NULL;
    struct node *rev_second = NULL;
    int i, temp, mul, ten, carry=0, sum = 0;
    rev_first = reverse(first);
    rev_second = reverse(second);

    while(rev_first != NULL)
    {
        ten = 1;
        carry = 0;   // LINE ADDED
        sum = 0;
        head = rev_second;
        while(head != NULL)
        {
            mul = (rev_first->data) * (head->data) + carry; // Added carry.
            carry = mul / 10;
            temp = mul % 10;
            sum = sum + (temp * ten);
            ten = ten * 10;
            head = head->next;
        }

        // ADDED THIS IF BLOCK.
        // If there is any carry, use it.
        if ( carry > 0 )
        {
           sum += carry * ten;
        }

        push(&ans, sum);
        printList(ans);
        rev_first = rev_first->next;
    }

    sum = 0;
    head = reverse(ans);
    for(mul = 1;head != NULL;(mul *= 10))
    {
        sum = sum + (mul * (head->data));
        head = head->next;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**PS**

The following function was helpful in tracking down the problem.

```
void printList(struct node* list)
{
   for ( ; list != NULL; list = list->next )
   {
      printf("%d ", list->data);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: your implementation of adding carry concept was correct and i accept it, but still the problem remains unsolved. Please add print statement in for loop to calculate final sum, to print sum at every step. You will see sum changes to garbage value in the last step.  for(mul=1;head!=NULL;mul*=10){...  printf("sum: %d",sum);}

Comment: @Chetankur, I don't see any problem. Checkout working code at http://ideone.com/zWfJav.

Comment: there was an issue with my compiler. I complied and executed on Ubuntu and it works perfectly fine there. Thank you for the valid inputs.